# Torsion of Coordinate Curves

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature, curvilinear-coordinates

Let $\sigma: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a regular conjugate parametrization. I would like to know a "proper" formulation of the torsion of coordinate curves of $\sigma$ with respect to the components of its first and second fundamental forms (i.e. $E,F,G,e,g$).

I naturally tried to do it by expanding $\det\,(\sigma_{uuu},\sigma_{uu},\sigma_u)$ with respect to the natural frame $\{\sigma_u,\sigma_v,N\}$ but resulted in a messy and long formula (I must add that I didn't try to simplify the obtained expression further since I thought there might be a wiser approach to it).

Comment: I do not understand the question. Please define precisely what you mean by "the torsion of coordinate curves of $\sigma$ with respect to ... its first and second fundamental forms."

Comment: @TedShifrin Since the coordinate curves of $\sigma(U)$ are themselves space curves they should have the torsion as a space curve. Additionally, since the changes of these  curves at each point of the curve can be described in the surface frame, that I mentioned above, it should be possible to write down its torsion according to the components of the surface fundamental forms.

Comment: How are you expecting to avoid the Christoffel symbols and their derivatives?

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't expect to avoid them.

Comment: OK. I don’t see anything to do other than brute force, unless perhaps there’s something special about the parametrization. If $F=0$ and the parameter curves are lines of curvature, perhaps you can expect something simpler.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ok, I see. Actually my surface is conjugate (f = 0).  I edit the post then.

Comment: @TedShifrin Actually, in order to have lines of curvature the parameterization should be orthogonal and conjugate at the same time (f = F = 0) not just (F = 0).

Comment: Yes, of course. I meant that $F=0$ was a simplification to try, and lines of curvature a further simplification.